# ASP.NET Gridview: How to Display Results from One Stored Procedure and Call Another Stored Procedure to Insert Data?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application that handles survey responses.  I want to dynamically serve the survey questions in a gridview control, and use the same gridview to permit the user to record their response.  Responses are saved in a separate table from the questions.

In essence, the gridview needs to pull the questions from one stored procedure and insert the responses entered in the gridview using another stored procedure.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt write how you are accesing database, is that any datasource control, linq ? 
i assume you would like to edit multiple rows, and then update the survey with one button

here you will find an [answer](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/edit-multiple-records-gridview-checkbox.html)

Comment: Sorry, using SQLDataSource to call a stored procedure to get the survey questions.  That stored procedure output will populate the gridview questions column.  I have a second stored procedure that handles the insertion of the responses.  How do I wire up the second stored procedure to grab the responses recorded in the gridview?  (I'm using the Ratings control from the AJAX Control Toolkit and also requesting text responses to the questions)